# Среда программирования для JavaScript. Что использовать?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, ide

Всем привет! Хотелось бы узнать мнение других людей. Кто что использует при программировании чисто на javascript? Я когда-то использовал Dreamveaver. Очень хорошая и удобная среда разработки для связки apache + PHP + mysql. Подсказка по коду html5, css3, jQuery и jQuery Mobile. Вот только один существенный минус (точнее 2, но о втором вы сами догадаетесь, я думаю), из-за которого пришлось поменять среду - нет подсветки парных скобок. При написании вложенных функций и циклов такая фича просто необходима. 
Долго присматривался к разным редакторам и средам разработки - открыл для себя Visual Studio Express for Web 2012. В нем есть все, что мне нужно, но вопрос с лицензией не понятен. Можно ли его использовать для коммерческой разработки?
Только не надо про notepad++ и всякие крутые блокноты. Мы это проходили.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Aptana Studio 3](http://www.aptana.com/) - поддерживает все ваши требования.
Я бы с удовольствием описал весь функционал, но проще увидеть. Кстати, есть интеграция с JQuery c автодоплнением и блэкджеком

Answer (score 1):

[SpKet IDE](http://spket.com)

Comment: Я знаю о существовании этого IDE. Хотелось бы мнение, а не ссылку. Используете ли сами в работе? Какие минусы, какие плюсы?

Comment: Дык это моё мнение..  Самый правильный вариант для чистого JavaScript.
Если нужен комплексный вариант, то NetBeans